# Ingresar string a un array mediante jTextField

Tags: java, array, java-swing, hilos

Les cuento mi problema:
Tengo que hacer una carrera de hilos, en la cual yo tengo que ingresar a los nombres mediante un jTextField y que al momento de presionar un jButton valide que no está vacío y lo muestre en un jTextArea y que lo almacene como atributo name en una clase encapsulada; y además de que solo permita 5 elementos, también debo de tener un método que genere un número aleatorio del 0 al 30, que añadí a la clase Runner. Pero no logro hacer que se muestren todos los corredores que ingreso, ya que al momento de ingresar un nuevo corredor, borra el anterior y no lo almacena en el atributo name de la clase Runner, les muestro mi codigo del array:

```
    int i=0;
    String[] nombres = new String[6];        
    private void btnRegistroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
   
    String corredores = registro.getText();
    nombres[i]=corredores;
    i++;
    
    if (nombres.length > i){
    jTextArea1.setText(corredores);
    }else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(registro, "Haz llegado al límite de corredores 
    permitidos", "Error",
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
       
    if (corredores.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(registro, "Este campo no puede estár vacío", 
    "Error",
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
    
    registro.setText("");       
    }
```

Este es mi clase que debe ser encapsulada Runner:

```
    package reto5;

    import java.util.Random;

    public class Runner {
    private String name;
    private int speed;

    
public Runner(String name, int speed){
    this.name = name;
    this.speed = speed;
}
Random rnd = new Random();
int valor = rnd.nextInt(30)+1;
```

}

Aún no se cómo hacer los hilos, primero quería resolver este tema del arreglo.

Gracias por sus comentarios, me serán de mucha ayuda.
Saludos.